# How to Implement Text Box with Gray Text Hint?

Tags: delphi, textbox, hint

In many website, I can see text box with hint in gray text. The hint will tell the user what should be inputted and whenever user tries to input anything, the hint will disappear.

Below is a sample of it:

[image]

I just wonder how to implement such a feature in Windows desktop application. I am using Delphi XE3 and it is possible to implement such a feature with TTextBox? Or is there such a VCL component available?

Comment: See the TEdit.TextHint property. It's in Seattle, Berlin and Tokyo. Not sure if it was available in XE3. If your Delphi version doesn't have it, upgrade to a more recent one.

Comment: .. or send an EM_SETCUEBANNER to the control.

Comment: @KenWhite, XE3 also has such a property, however, after I set it, the text hint does not appear even when .Text is empty. I see document said "Runtime themes must be enabled". what does that mean?

Comment: Themes are automatically enabled. See Project->Options->Application; there's a checkbox that says *Enable runtime themes*. The TextHint only appears if the edit's text is empty and it does not have focus.

Comment: @alancc your app must have a manifest that specifies a dependancy on ComCtl32.dll v6 in order to [enable Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/cookbook-overview). Modern Delphi  versions do that by default, and can be [configured in the project settings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Application_Options). XE3 has an [enable runtime themes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Application_Options) option for that.

Comment: @KenWhite, Still does not work even after I set to Enable runtime themes. Maybe this does not work under WIndows XP.

Comment: No, requires Vista and up.

Comment: You didn't say you were using XP. That ancient, no longer supported OS does not support text hints. It's only supported on Vista and above, IIRC. It's an important detail that you should have provided in your original question; it's an OS that is not supported by MS at all any longer and is not officially supported by Delphi.

Comment: How did you take that screen shot, with a browser that doesn't support the OS?

Comment: @KenWhite, Sorry about that. I originally thought that the feature is introduced by new version of Delphi, not related to OS.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, I just use another computer and use FireFox to make a screenshot to express my idea.

Comment: @Sami The question is about the `TextHint` property, available in both `TEdit` and `TLabeledEdit`

Comment: @Sami `TLabeledEdit` just populates external `TBoundLabel` component. It is not the same what OP wants. There is enough standard `TEdit` component.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Actually, `EM_SETCUEBANNER` for Edit controls does work on XP, but only if an East Asian language pack is not installed. What doesn't work at all on XP is `CB_SETCUEBANNER` for ComboBoxes

Comment: @dummzeuch the feature could also be implemented by simply subclassing the Edit control to handle the `WM_PAINT` message to draw the hint text when the Edit text is empty

Comment: @Sami: The poster is asking about the text hint (the grey letters inside the edit that offer information to the user about what belongs in that edit). It applies to both TEdit and TLabeledEdit as well; neither of them support that functionality on XP, as it wasn't introduced in the OS until Vista.

Comment: @Sami: The label is irrelevant, whether it's part of a TLabeledEdit or just a separate TLabel. Ignore the label. It's the Texthint (the text **inside the edit** that the poster is asking about. Read the post, where it talks about *grey text*.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an implementation that works for Windows XP (and also Windows 7 and 8.1, haven't tested it on Windows 10). Beware: I mostly use it in Windows XP and 8.1 and with Delphi 2007 and XE2. There may be bugs that I haven't seen yet.

It's also probably not the most elegant solution but it works and is easy to understand.

Prerequisites: [Delphi Custom Containers Pack](https://blog.dummzeuch.de/delphi-custom-containers-pack/)

Just save the following to u_dzCueEdit.dfm and u_dzCueEdit.pas, create a runtime package with it, create a corresponding design time package with a Register procedure and install it.

dfm file:

```
object dzCueEdit: TdzCueEdit
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Width = 258
  Height = 21
  TabOrder = 0
  OnResize = BoxResize
  object ed_Cue: TEdit
    Left = 1
    Top = 1
    Width = 256
    Height = 19
    Align = alClient
    TabOrder = 0
    OnChange = ed_CueChange
    OnClick = ed_CueClick
    OnEnter = ed_CueEnter
    OnExit = ed_CueExit
  end
  object p_Cue: TPanel
    Left = 64
    Top = 0
    Width = 242
    Height = 21
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    Color = clMoneyGreen
    ParentBackground = False
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = p_CueClick
    OnEnter = p_CueEnter
    object l_Cue: TLabel
      AlignWithMargins = True
      Left = 88
      Top = 0
      Width = 93
      Height = 13
      Margins.Left = 1
      Margins.Top = 1
      Margins.Right = 1
      Margins.Bottom = 1
      Caption = 'Cue text goes here'
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clGray
      Font.Height = -11
      Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
      Font.Style = []
      ParentFont = False
      OnClick = l_CueClick
    end
  end
end
```

pas file:
unit c_dzCueEdit;

```
interface

uses
  Windows,
  Messages,
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Graphics,
  Controls,
  Forms,
  Dialogs,
  ExtCtrls,
  StdCtrls,
  ccBoxes;

type
  TdzCueEdit = class(TBox)
    p_Cue: TPanel;
    l_Cue: TLabel;
    procedure ed_CueClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure l_CueClick(Sender: TObject);
  published
    ed_Cue: TEdit;
    procedure p_CueEnter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure p_CueClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ed_CueChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ed_CueEnter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ed_CueExit(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BoxResize(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure CheckCueBanner;
    function GetCue: string;
    function GetText: string;
    procedure SetCue(const _Value: string);
    procedure SetText(const _Value: string);
  protected
  public
    constructor Create(_Owner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property Text: string read GetText write SetText;
    property Cue: string read GetCue write SetCue;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

{ TdzCueEdit }

constructor TdzCueEdit.Create(_Owner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  BevelOuter := bvNone;
  l_Cue.Align := alClient;
  p_Cue.Color := ed_Cue.Color;
end;

procedure TdzCueEdit.BoxResize(Sender: TObject);
var
  Rect: TRect;
begin
  Rect := ed_Cue.ClientRect;
//  p_Cue.SetBounds(Rect.Left, Rect.Top, Rect.Right - Rect.Left, Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top);
  p_Cue.SetBounds(Rect.Left + 4, Rect.Top + 3, Rect.Right - Rect.Left - 2, Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top - 2);
end;

procedure TdzCueEdit.CheckCueBanner;
begin
  if ed_Cue.Text <> '' then
    p_Cue.Visible := False
  else begin
//    if ed_Cue.Focused then
//      p_Cue.Visible := False
//    else
      p_Cue.Visible := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TdzCueEdit.ed_CueChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CheckCueBanner;
end;

procedure TdzCueEdit.ed_CueClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CheckCueBanner;
end;

procedure TdzCueEdit.ed_CueEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CheckCueBanner;
end;

procedure TdzCueEdit.ed_CueExit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CheckCueBanner;
end;

function TdzCueEdit.GetCue: string;
begin
  Result := l_Cue.Caption;
end;

procedure TdzCueEdit.SetCue(const _Value: string);
begin
  l_Cue.Caption := _Value;
end;

function TdzCueEdit.GetText: string;
begin
  Result := ed_Cue.Text;
end;

procedure TdzCueEdit.l_CueClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ed_Cue.SetFocus;
  CheckCueBanner;
end;

procedure TdzCueEdit.SetText(const _Value: string);
begin
  ed_Cue.Text := _Value;
end;

procedure TdzCueEdit.p_CueClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ed_Cue.SetFocus;
  CheckCueBanner;
end;

procedure TdzCueEdit.p_CueEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ed_Cue.SetFocus;
  CheckCueBanner;
end;

end.
```